# Using both lombok and protobuf results in gradle tasks without dependencies resulting in builds failing sometimes

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers, lombok

I use lombok and protobuf simultaneously in gradle. This generates the tasks `generateEffectiveLombokConfig` and `generateProto` which are independent. Yet the lombok task should depend on the protobuf task, otherwise the code generated by lombok is referring to Java code not yet generated by protoc.

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
package my.example.v1;
message Task {
  string id = 1;
  repeated string names_to_print = 2;
}
```

```java
package org.example;

import lombok.experimental.UtilityClass;
import my.example.v1.*;

@UtilityClass
public class Worker {

    public void work(TaskOuterClass.Task task) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '6.4.3'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.18'
}

group 'org.example'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.20.1"
    implementation "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.20.1"
}
```

I tried to add the output of protobuf as sourceSet to make sure the protobuf task is performed first, yet I get a warning:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "${projectDir}/build/generated/source/proto/main/java"
        }
    }
}
```

warning:

```
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':generateProto' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/build/generated/source/proto/main'. Reason: Task ':generateEffectiveLombokConfig' uses this output of task ':generateProto' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

How can I make sure that all protobuf tasks are done before the lombok tasks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you put task dependency as below

```
afterEvaluate {
    generateEffectiveLombokConfig.mustRunAfter generateProto
}
```

```
Executing 'build -m'...

:extractIncludeProto SKIPPED
:extractProto SKIPPED
:generateProto SKIPPED
:generateEffectiveLombokConfig SKIPPED
:compileJava SKIPPED
:processResources SKIPPED
:classes SKIPPED
:jar SKIPPED
:assemble SKIPPED
:generateTestEffectiveLombokConfig SKIPPED
:extractIncludeTestProto SKIPPED
:extractTestProto SKIPPED
:generateTestProto SKIPPED
:compileTestJava SKIPPED
:processTestResources SKIPPED
:testClasses SKIPPED
:test SKIPPED
:check SKIPPED
:build SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 299ms
```

Comment: Thanks @PrasadU that solves the issue. Now I have a follow-up question. If I also use `java { withJavadocJar() }` in the `build.gradle` a task `delombok` is executed which fails as it is not able to find the files generated by protoc. I tried to add `delombok.mustRunAfter generateProto` yet that does not solve the issue.